# Using %>% and ifelse() inside a function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I would like to run a function to test if a value exists in a dataset or not. I've looked for answers and since found a workaround but it's not as neat and I'm curious why my initial attempt failed.

Here's a simplified dataset

```
df <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("IRE","USA"), 
class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1990", "1995", "2000"),
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
  country year
1     IRE 1990
2     IRE 1995
3     IRE 2000
4     USA 1990
5     USA 1995
6     USA 2000
```

I would like my function to return a `1` if a particular country code and year are present or a `0` otherwise. This is the working code:

```
myFunc <- function(x,y){
  p.ans <- df %>% filter(year == y) 
  ifelse(x %in% p.ans$country, 1, 0)
}

> myFunc("USA", 1995)
[1] 1

> myFunc("USA", 1997)
[1] 0
```

But why doesn't this alternative code work? Is there a variation of it that would?

```
myFunc <- function(x,y){
  df %>% filter(year == y) %>% ifelse(x %in% country, 1, 0)
}

> myFunc("USA", 1997)
 Error in ifelse(., x %in% country, 1, 0) : unused argument (0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to return `1` or `0` instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But why doesn't this alternative code work?

Because `x %>% f(y)` is the same as `f(x, y)`. Thus the code you wrote is equal to

```
ifelse(filter(df, year == y), x %in% country, 1, 0)
```

… which is not how the `ifelse` function works.

Instead, you could write

```
df %>% filter(year == y) %>% pull(country) %>% {ifelse(x %in% ., 1, 0)}
```

Here you need to surround the `ifelse` function call with `{…}` to prevent the pipe from inserting the right-hand side as the first argument into the function call (we want to use `x %in% .` as the first argument rather than just `.`).

… or, if you’ve loaded the ‘magrittr’ package, you can use `%$%` instead of `%>% pull(…) %>% {…}`:

```
df %>% filter(year == y) %$% ifelse(x %in% country, 1, 0)
```